# knowledge base transitivity rule

Tags: prolog

I have this knowledge base:

```
implements(expression, funcall).
implements(expression, identifier).
implements(specialForm, conditional).
implements(literal, boole).

extends(expression, specialForm).
extends(expression, literal).
extends(value, literal).

has(conditional, condition, expression).
has(conditional, consequent, expression).
has(conditional, alternative, expression).
has(funcall, operator, identifier).
has(funcall, operands, expression).

%if class/interface X depends on class/interface Y.
%dep(X,Y):- X=Y.
dep(X,Y):- extends(Y,X).
dep(X,Y):- has(X,_,Y).
dep(X,Y):- implements(X,Y).

depends(X,Y):- X = Y.
depends(X, Y) :- dep(X,Y).
depends(X, Y) :- dif(Z,Y), dep(X,Z),depends(Z,Y).
```

[image]

the deps method just check if the 2 values extends, implements, or has one another. The depends method is to check for dependencies where there is more than 1 link required. For example, boole should be dependent on expression, but if I call the function depends(boole,expression), I get false. Why?

Comment: Did you try doing a `trace` to see where your logic goes?

Comment: `depends(boole, expression)` succeeds only if `dep(boole, expression)` succeeds, which only succeeds if either `extends(expression, boole)` succeeds (nope, no facts match), or if `has(boole, _, expression)` succeeds (nope again, no facts match), or if `implements(boole, expression)` suceeds, (nope again, no facts match).

Comment: I'm confused. Your problem statement said your query fails (comes back false). But you are saying when you run `trace` it's an infinite loop. It can't be both. `depends` is not properly defined. You probably want, `depends(X, Y) :- dep(X, Y).` and `depends(X, Y) :- dep(X, Z), depends(Z, Y).`.

Comment: I made a mistake, I was thinking about something else. This is what i get:depends(boole,expression).
   Call: (8) depends(boole, expression) ? Unknown option (h for help)
   Call: (8) depends(boole, expression) ? creep
   Call: (9) boole=expression ? creep
   Fail: (9) boole=expression ?

Comment: See my prior comments for explanation of what's wrong. The trace is giving you details about what I said was causing it to fail.

Comment: I had that before and then i got an infinite loop from that

Comment: I tried the code I suggested for you and I do not get an infinite loop on the query, `depends(boole,expression).`. But you may need to use `dif/2`:  `depends(X, Y) :- dif(Z, Y), dep(X, Z), depends(Z, Y).` if you have other facts you are not showing.

Comment: I don't get an infinite loop either. It returns false when I do `depends(boole,expression).`. Why don't you try running `trace, depends(boole,expression)`.

Comment: lurker, I tried to do what you did but when I executed depends(boole,expression), I get false when i want true. I have edited the main post to my new program, as well as a UML disgram showing the relationship.

Comment: I tried doing this: depends(X, Y) :- dif(Z, Y), dep(X, Z), depends(Z, Y). and i get false. if i try doing this: dif/2: depends(X, Y) :- dif(Z, Y), dep(X, Z), depends(Z, Y).  I get a compile error

Comment: Yes, and I explained why it yields false in my prior comment. Please examine your facts and trace the logic. Your facts and rules indicate that the result should be false. So perhaps your facts are not correct. And NO do not put the `dif/2:` in front of the code I showed you. I was explaining that you need to use `dif/2` by prefacing my comment with "`dif/2`:" It still will not succeed with `dif/2`, however, since the facts are still probably your problem. The `dif/2` will just prevent possible infinite loop in some cases. It's not magic.

Answer (score 3):

You have the sense of `literal/2` reversed in your `dep/2` implementation.

Instead of:

```
dep(X, Y) :- implements(X, Y).
```

You should have:

```
dep(X, Y) :- implements(Y, X).
```

You should also get rid of `depends(X, Y) :- X = Y.` unless you have a very specific reason for `depends/2` being reflexive. But in your problem context, it would seem odd to say that, for example, "Number depends upon Number".